# Map on DataSet executing twice while count operation even DataSet has schema

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, dataset, apache-spark-sql

DsDetails contains one record but inside logic(API) in map calling two times because performing count() operation

Is there any way that can control iteration of this map or how to prevent this multiple iteration?

It is major problem to achieve better performance.

Below code is written in Java,

Code written in driver program,

```
  batchNumerDetails.foreachRDD(xJavaRdd -> {
    Encoder<detailSchema> detailEncoder = Encoders.bean(detailSchema.class);
    Dataset<Row> batchDF = SparkUtil.ConvertToDataSet(sparkSession, xJavaRdd);  
    //Input 1 row 
    Dataset<detailSchema> detailsDf = DsDetails.map(new MapFunction<Row, String>() {
                @Override
                public detailSchema call(Row row) {
                 // Unfortunately calling this method 2 times
                    detailSchema objdetailSchema = new detailSchema();
                    detailSchema.Id = "2";
                    detailSchema.Name =  GetNameAPICall(row.<String>getAs("details"));
                    return objdetailSchema;
                }
            }, detailEncoder);

    // Because of count, It map is executing twice
    System.out.println(detailsDf.count());
     // output 1 row
});
```

detailsSchema.java

```
Public class detailSchema
{
    public String Id;
    public String Name;

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we call action(Count) on RDD, each time map will recompute "from scratch" that's why it is iterating multiple times.

So after completion of Map You can cache this result and then perform action on it to avoid multiple call on Map.

So After Map Code will look like,

```
detailsDf.cache();
System.out.println(detailsDf.count());
```